# what is resultPageFactory in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module

what is `resultPageFactory` in magento 2 and what is the use of it ?

Answer (score 13):

**General**
In Magento 2 all controller actions must return something, opposed to M1, where a controller action would just output something or did a redirect.
The result of the `execute` method from each controller is generated in `Magento\Framework\App\FrontController::dispatch()` on line `$result = $actionInstance->execute();` and returned.

Depending on the type of the returned result a different action is performed.
The result can be and instance of :

- `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page` - actually renders html
- `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect` - redirects to an other page
- `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward` - forwards to an other action (internal redirect)
- `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json` - returns a json object.
- `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw` - returns whatever you tell it to return (string).

**Specific**
`resultPageFactory` is an instance of `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory` and when calling `create` on that class it returns an instance of `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page` described above.
When this is used and the result is returned it means that your action will return HTML.
It has somehow a similar effect as `$this->loadLayout();` from Magento 1.
When you call `create` on the `resultPageFactory` object it actually loads the layout

Comment: Very helpful :)